# New to Linux problem with virtual env in Pycharm / Python

Tags: python, linux, pip, pycharm, fedora

I am new to Linux (Fedora) and I have a problem.
I am using Pycharm Professional and I have made a virtual env, and that works great i installed all the packages and in the Pycharm terminal and everything works
But when I open system Terminal and then go to the project directory, active virtual env I am not able to use pip

Pycharm terminal - works
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMBn1.png)

Sys terminal - error
[Image 2 new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njs8b.png)

I reinstalled pip but still the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what the Polish (?) text means. [StackOverflow rules state English only](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). If you could please translate or run `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8` and run the `pip` command again, that would be great.

Comment: Okay I added a new screenshot

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return under each shell environment?

Comment: SYSTEM TERMINAL: `/home/kacper/Projects/fb-checker/ven/bin:/home/kacper/.local/bin:/home/kacper/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin`





PYCHARM TERMINAL: 
`/home/kacper/Projects/fb-checker/ven/bin:/app/bin:/app/extensions/bin:/usr/bin
`

Comment: `/app/bin` being in the Pycharm environment tells me it must be executing *inside* a Docker container, which is automatically going to have a different environment from what you'll get from popping open a system terminal. If you find the appropriate container name (run `docker ps`) you can try running `docker exec -it TheContainName bash` which'll pop open the same shell in your terminal.

Comment: Okej i fixed this. Pycharm is using Python 3.11 by default on Fedora but i had installed Python 3.12.
I installed Python 3.11 set it as a default version and it works now

Comment: you can always try `python -m pip ...` instead of `pip ....` and it should run `pip` for correct `python`